# Is there any way to optimize this MySQL query when merging two query?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to get the result with product_id, stock, new_cost

```
SELECT inventory_logs.product_id, ROUND(SUM(inventory_logs.qty + 0), 4) AS stock
FROM products
JOIN inventory_logs on products.id = inventory_logs.product_id
WHERE inventory_logs.`type` = 'as'
AND inventory_logs.`created_at` between '1970-01-01' and '2021-02-22 23:59:59'
AND inventory_logs.`branch_id` = 1
AND inventory_logs.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND products.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY inventory_logs.product_id HAVING stock > 0
```

above that is the query for getting stock,
duration for query is about 0.031 sec

```
SELECT inventory_logs.product_id, inventory_logs.new_cost
FROM inventory_logs JOIN(
    SELECT product_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
    FROM inventory_logs
    WHERE created_at <= '2021-02-22 23:59:59' AND deleted_at IS NULL
    AND `type` = 'as'
    AND inventory_logs.`branch_id` = 1
    GROUP BY product_id
) i2 ON (inventory_logs.product_id = i2.product_id AND inventory_logs.created_at = i2.created_at)
WHERE `type` = 'as'
AND inventory_logs.`branch_id` = 1
```

above is the query for getting new_cost, duration for query is also about 0.031 sec

But when I try to merge the above two query into one, the duration of query is 26.016 sec
The query is

```
SELECT inventory_logs.product_id, ROUND(SUM(inventory_logs.qty = 0), 4) AS stock, sub.new_cost
FROM products
JOIN inventory_logs ON products.id = inventory_logs.product_id
JOIN (
    SELECT inventory_logs.product_id, inventory_logs.new_cost
    FROM inventory_logs JOIN (
        SELECT product_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at
        FROM inventory_logs
        WHERE created_at <= '2021-02-22 23:59:59' AND deleted_at IS NULL
        AND `type` = 'as'
        AND inventory_logs.`branch_id` = 1
        GROUP BY product_id
     ) i2 ON (inventory_logs.product_id = i2.product_id AND inventory_logs.vreated_at 
     = i2.created_at)
    WHERE `type` = 'as'
    AND inventory_logs.`branch_id` = 1
) sub ON products.id = sub.product_id
WHERE inventory_logs.`type` = 'as'
AND inventory_logs.`created_at` BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '2021-02-22 23:59:59'
AND inventory_logs.`branch_id` = 1
AND inventory_logs.`deleted_at` IS NULL
AND products.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY inventory_logs.product_id HAVING stock > 0
```

Is there any ways to optimize the above query to make it take lesser time?

Comment: Avoid subquery in FROM, forget about existing partial queries and build new query from the same beginning. Use CTE and window function if MySQL version allows.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query